# Rearrange array on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do I rearrange the data in the format below, where the least value is put at the far right, the next value at the far left, the next at the one-but-last position,... etc, working towards the center:

```
var data = [22, 1, 3, 70, 20, 60, 4, 10];
output = [3, 10, 22, 70, 60, 20, 4, 1]
```

Comment: This is the exact question I wanna ask *How do I rearrange the data in the mentioned format*? What kind of sorting is this. Would you explain?

Comment: can you share the logic of sorting in this strange format and dividing into rows.

Comment: "And also": you should only ask one question.

Comment: @trincot I see my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort the data and then distribute values into a new array, in zigzag order:

```js
function spread(data) {
    let n = data.length;
    // First sort
    let sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) => a - b);
    // Then spread
    let result = Array(n);
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; j < n; i++, j += 2) {
        result[i] = sorted[j + 1];     // zig...
        result[n - 1 - i] = sorted[j]; // zag
    }
    return result;
}

// Demo
var data = [22, 1, 3, 70, 20, 60, 4, 10];
let result = spread(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach by using an object for swappign methods.

```js
function f(array, first, second) {
    const
        result = [],
        swap = { unshift: 'push', push: 'unshift' };

    array
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .forEach((fn => v => result[fn = swap[fn]](v))('push'));

    return result;
}

console.log(...f([22, 1, 3, 70, 20, 60, 4, 10]));
```

Answer (score 0):

- `sort` the array
- Get the keys of the array using `Array.from(data.keys())`

  ```
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  ```
- Move all the even keys to the end and odd keys to the front.
- If both the keys being compared are odd, then sort the keys in ascending order.
- If both the keys are even, then sort them in descending order.
- You get an array like this: `[1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 0]`. Then, `map` this indices array to get the data for each index:

```js
const data = [22, 1, 3, 70, 20, 60, 4, 10]

data.sort((a, b) => a - b)

const output = Array.from(data.keys())
                    .sort((a, b) => (b % 2 - a % 2) || (a % 2 ? a - b : b - a))
                    .map(i => data[i])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: looks familiar ...

Comment: @NinaScholz I probably got this idea from one of your answers on some similar question :)

Comment: @NinaScholz I was looking for that duplicate. I didn't look for *normal distribution*.